# React Algolia how to get searchbar in nav and result in body?

Tags: reactjs, nav, algolia

I have this react algolia component which works

```
const AlgoliaSearchBar = ({ instantSearchParams, className }) => {
    const { instantSearchProps } = instantSearchParams || {};

    return (
      <div className={"flex " + className}>
        <div className="flex-auto mt-6" style={{width: '400px'}}>
            <InstantSearch
              {...instantSearchProps}
              searchClient={searchClient}
              indexName="instant_search"
              insights={true}
            >
                <SearchBoxWithSuggestions />

                <Configure hitsPerPage={16} />

                <CurrentRefinements
                  className="current-refinements"
                  includedAttributes={['query', 'categories']}
                />

                <RenderHits />
             
            </InstantSearch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default AlgoliaSearchBar;



const RenderHits= ({ column }) => {
    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className={`container-column${column}`}>
                <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default RenderHits;
```

So this code works when I keep call the AlgoliaSearchBar in a div container.

But what I want is to have the search bar in the nav. And if I call the AlgoliaSearchBar in my nav it also tries to render all the hits in the nav, and not looks good.

So how do I sperate my RenderHits to the body and keep the searchbar in the nav?

Comment: where is the nav bar defined? wrap navbar also inside `<InstantSearch>`? and in the navbar have the search component?

Comment: @cmgchess Yes I wrapped my hole  app in InstantSearch and it worked. Thanks